# R 4.1.2 could not find X11 headers/libs after specifying --x-includes and --x-libraries

Tags: r, linux, x11

I am trying to install a local R version on a ubuntu server. The server has X11 installed

```
➜  X11 pwd
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/include/X11
➜  X11 ls
ap_keysym.h   HookObjI.h    ResourceI.h   Xatom.h       Xos.h
CallbackI.h   HPkeysym.h    SelectionI.h  Xauth.h       Xos_r.h
...
```

and I can find the required headers for example `IntrinsicI.h`. However, when I configure R using the following command, it failed to recognize those headers even after I told R where they are.

```
➜  R-4.1.2 ./configure --prefix=$HOME/R \\
--x-includes=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/include/X11 \\
--x-libraries=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib
```

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? What code do you run when you get the error? Are you trying to compile R yourself? Does the error happen at the configure step or the make step?

Comment: any reason not to just install the R ubuntu package ? `sudo apt install r-base`

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, The error says that R could not find `X11/IntrinsicI.h`. The`-with-x` flag is set but the headers/includes of X11 cannot be found.  I ran the command I showed above when I got the error. I am trying to compile R by myself because I want to use it on a Linux server, where I don't have root access. The error happened at the configure step, when I ran the command I show above.

Comment: Hi @KarlForner, this is because I am using a Linux server where I have no root access.

Comment: can you use docker ? if so you could use the prebuilt rocker docker images...